# Eclipse won't stop using Java SE1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-8

I have been receiving errors when trying to run a Java program with my plugin that look like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: REALDrummer/myCoreLibrary : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:77) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1496]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1496]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:40) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1496]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:127) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-1496]
    ... 6 more
```

From what I understand from other posts, this means that I'm compiling my plugin in Java 8 while running it on a JVM with Java 7. I know that I'm running a Java 7 JVM; I'm actually doing that on purpose to make sure that it's compatible with Java 7 for other people's use.

**The problem is that I can't seem to get Eclipse to stop compiling in Java 8 and use Java 7.** I have set the default JRE to Java 7 (OpenJDK Java 7) within the "Installed JREs" preference and I've noted that the Java 7 JRE is the one whose standard library now appears in the project. The Java 7 JRE is also the one that appears in the "Libraries" tab in the Java Build Path.

Despite all this, I'm still getting this error. Is there another setting I need to change to make Eclipse compile in Java 7 instead of Java 8? I don't have any Java 8 elements in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassingly, I finally found the answer *after* I posted this question. There is in fact another setting.

Changing `Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level` to "1.7" finally got it to compile with Java 7.

Comment: @mlkammer Done. Thanks for pointing that out. I couldn't at the time I made it because I had to wait 24 hours.